# How to set the dropUp for AngularJS multiselect dropdown

Tags: angularjs

As i am using AngularJS multiselect dropdown but in this below source i can't find the dropUp functionality like as bootstrap multiselect. So i want dropUp functionality as well so any one can help for the code.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.multiselect']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.cars = [{id:1, name: 'Audi'}, {id:2, name: 'BMW'}, {id:1, name: 'Honda'}];
    $scope.selectedCar = [];

    $scope.fruits = [{id: 1, name: 'Apple'}, {id: 2, name: 'Orange'},{id: 3, name: 'Banana'}];
    $scope.selectedFruit = null;
});
```

reference link AngularJS multiselect
http://plnkr.co/edit/LPGYIf?p=preview

Thanks in advance,

Comment: do add more details to your requirement. What do you mean by `dropup`

Comment: DropUp means when we are opening the Dropdown it's open down but when the dropdown close to screen bottom it should show to top that is called dropUp functionality. i am adding bootstrap multiselect here you can see how it works in bootstrap dropdown. and just compare to both. http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/